Custom makeBody @MainActor ButtonStyle triggers warning on makeBody with strict concurrency enabled
In Xcode 15, when enabling strict concurrency, many warning are triggered and most of these found an easy resolution in annotating most, if not all, UI classes with @MainActor or similar refactorings.
One warning I can't get rid of though is the following:

Main actor-isolated instance method 'makeBody(configuration:)' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement

on the makeBody(configuration:) implementation.
@MainActor
struct PrimaryButton: ButtonStyle {
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View { // WARNING
        configuration.label
            .customStyle(property) // using ui-layer properties isolated to main actor)
    }
}

The reason is clear but I cannot see a solution beside:

Declaring makeBody nonisolated is impractical since the body of the function will require many accesses to MainActor isolated properties.
On the other hand removing the @MainActor annotation would make the use of this class impractical in View instances, since they are all MainActor isolated.

Am I overcomplicating and doing something wrong architecturally with async/await and structured concurrency, or is there an easy way to solve this in a performant and practical way?

You'll have to "await" the MainActor isolated properties, present a ProgressView

But this is a button style, it is used potentially in hundreds of instances in Lists, VStacks, in loops, etc. Multiply this for each of the dozens properties to be awaited for, and i don't really see me trusting it's performances. Besides, it is a painful process, this is not the only class that has this kind of issues.

It sounds like someone coded some pretty serious concurrency flaws into your code then, youll need a full revamp. People using MainActor for everything is a huge issue right now, your peoject isn’t the only one.

I have this suspect, and I am guilty as well, but structured concurrency is insanely strict; stable and reliable and simple patterns have yet to emerge, and the SwiftUI not being fully on paar with it doesn't help. Anyway aren't View automatically executed on MainActor? If so code that is strictly used in views like a ButtonStyle shouldn't also be expected to commit to the same isolation?

No, it is a common misconception. Only the Body is forced on the MainActor. SwiftUI works well with the new concurrency, but it does take time to adapt.

@loremipsum i refactored the whole thing and yes, using Sendable in place of MainActor makes much more sense now and everything fits much better. If you want you can write it as an answer and i accept it.
